# Prevent Scrollviewer from Scrolling just before printing?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xps

I'm trying to print my visual into a multipage xps. The first page is working but the others are left blank.

```
Dim xP As Integer = 0
Dim yP As Integer = 0
xP = Math.Ceiling(WorkFlowCanvas.Width / pageWidth)
yP = Math.Ceiling(WorkFlowCanvas.Height / pageHeight)
Dim collator = writer.CreateVisualsCollator()
collator.BeginBatchWrite()
For y = 1 To yP
    For x = 1 To xP
        Dim o As New Canvas
        o = New CanvasCreator().GenerateCanvas()
        Dim sv As New ScrollViewer
        sv.Height = 1200
        sv.Width = 800
        sv.Content = o
        sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(x - 1 * sv.Width)
        sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset(y - 1 * sv.Height)
        sv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled
        sv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled
        collator.Write(sv)
    Next
Next
collator.Write(Me)
collator.EndBatchWrite()
```

By making the visual in xaml and printing it I noticed the scrollviewer always scrolls the content up before writing it(the scrollbars don't move). Is there a way to 'freeze' the scrollviewer?

Comment: I'm no VB expert, but it looks to me like you missed some parens:
`sv.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((x - 1) * sv.Width)`
`sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset((y - 1) * sv.Height)`

Comment: I have changed it but it didn't work. Thx for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is hacky but it seems to work for me.

```
            sv.IsEnabled = False
            collator.Write(sv)
            sv.IsEnabled = True
```

You can stil answer if you know why I have to do this.