# c# WPF scroll view Prints based on scroll location

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll

I have built an app on WPF C# that holds invoices and I have created a usercontrol that is assigned to a scrollview.
Everything works perfect until I notice this really anoying printing bug.

So the user control is in the size of an A4. If the scroll view is scrolled to the top at the time of printing :

```
 **PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrintVisual(scrollView, "print this off");**
```

No issues occur. However, if the scroll view is in middle or bottom it prints with an offset.
I have tried to remedy it by moving the scrollview to the top before printing and it does so but the prints come out wrong...

```
**scrollView.ScrollToHome();
            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrintVisual(scrollView, "print this off");**
```

and yet if I Hit the print button again it will print correctly. I have no idea why it prints before moving it to top as thats the only explanation I have for it...

PLEASE HELP

Comment: try to pass the instance of your control to the `PrintVisual` method, instead of the scrollView that contains it.

Comment: tried that still the same result, tried passing usercontrol a new user control instance a new scrollview instance everything comes out the saem :(

Comment: ok. it seems odd that a new instance of the control which is created from scratch, populated with data and never assigned to a scrollable container, would assume any y-offset when printing. are you positive that you attempt with a the new control instance that does not inherit/assign any container(s)?

Comment: it will have the same user control, maybe im missunderstanding you this is my first WPF project so im a bit of a noob when it comes to controls :)

Comment: maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10981996/prevent-scrollviewer-from-scrolling-just-before-printing

Comment: I could not repro the problem with a very minimal sample WPF app consisting of just a ScrollViewer and a Panel. A shot in the dark: try to call `scrollView.UpdateLayout()` after your call to `scrollView.ScrollToHome()`. The docs of the `UpdateLayout()` function say, "Ensures that all visual child elements of this element are properly updated for layout.", and that sounds like what we want.

Comment: thanks the UpdateLayout()  worked absolutely brilliant.

Comment: glad it helped. posted my comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call `UpdateLayout()` after scrolling home:

```
scrollView.ScrollToHome();
scrollView.UpdateLayout();
```

(from the docs of the UpdateLayout() function: "Ensures that all visual child elements of this element are properly updated for layout.")

Answer (score 0):

this worked like a charm and simpler than implementing threading. Both good answers

I could not repro the problem with a very minimal sample WPF app consisting of just a ScrollViewer and a Panel. A shot in the dark: try to call `scrollView.UpdateLayout()` after your call to `scrollView.ScrollToHome()`. The docs of the UpdateLayout() function say, "Ensures that all visual child elements of this element are properly updated for layout.", and that sounds like what we want. – dlatikay

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem before when I change layout of a Visual right before print action. If I print immediately, I will get wrong result. I guess that the Visual don't have enough time to render properly new layout before you print. I fixed like this:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

async void Print() // Use async
{
    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    scrollView.ScrollToHome();
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)); // Wait 1 second scrollView being properly rendered.
    pd.PrintVisual(scrollView, "print this off");
}
```

Comment: assuming an arbitrarily complex layout, and other processes using CPU, your delay approach will increase the chance that it works properly in many cases, but is not a reliable fix.